# JQUERY: Uncaught error: Syntax error #

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm programming with JQuery (v3.2.1) and I am getting an error

> JQUERY: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

The code I have is:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "updateFieldDesc.php",
     data: "idTerminal=" + idTerminal + "&aplicacion=" + aplicacion + "&nombre_campo=" + nombre_campo,
     success:function (output) {
       var salida = output.split("|");
       var idCampo = salida[0];
       var descripcion = salida[1];

       //console.log("**********output :"  + idCampo );
       $("#" + idCampo).html(descripcion);
     }
   });
 })
}
```

And the error is caused by the line: `$("#" + idCampo).html(description)`

How do I fix this error?

Comment: looks like your idCampo is null 
what the console show if you uncomment //console.log("**********output :"  + idCampo );?

Comment: @Max good idea, but why would a null reference cause a syntax error?

Comment: @Max `$("#"+null)` / `$("#"+undefined)` / `$("#")` results in `null` in chrome not a Syntax Error.

Comment: I think the question is: what *exactly* is the value of `idCampo` - also, is that the full error or have you removed part when copying to the question?

Comment: @Javr In general there seems nothing wrong with the statement itself however, without knowing what the value of  `idCampo` is it's hard to help out. It also would help to see the element markup your value ends up referring too.

Comment: lol I'm too tired sry guys, my bad.

Comment: @Javr, what other library you are using beside jquery?

Comment: I have removed the quotation marks from  console.log("**********output :" + idCampo ) and shows an empty value. Ex:" **********output :       "  .                            
I'm using Bootstrap and jquery-ui

Comment: can u post updateFieldDesc.php ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `idCampo` is a space (or other similar whitespace).

If your console log is:

```
console.log("**********output :" + idCampo )
```

and it gives `" **********output : "`

there's no space in your console log after the colon, but there is in your example output, which appears to be "empty".  I always recommend a console log such as:

```
console.log("output : [" + idCampo + "]")
```

which, in this case should output as:  `[ ]`  (as opposed to empty `[]`)

A quick snippet to show that `$("# ")` gives the same error you're getting:

```js
try {
var space = " ";
$("#" + space).show();  
} catch (e) {
console.log(e.message)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```